# The name "e" does not exist under the current context error in DrawText method

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am rendering some Bitmaps in a method I wrote in C#.

I am learning to use the `TextRenderer.DrawText()` method to draw text onto the bitmap. The snippet is as follows:

`TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Regular Text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new Point(10, 10), SystemColors.ControlText);`

However, under `e.Graphics`, I am given the error that `The name "e" does not exist under the current context`.

I was wondering what could be the issue?

The code snippet from my Render method, using the Rhino-Common library:

```
    protected override void Render(Grasshopper.GUI.Canvas.GH_Canvas canvas, Graphics graphics, Grasshopper.GUI.Canvas.GH_CanvasChannel channel) {
        base.Render(canvas, graphics, channel);

        if (channel == Grasshopper.GUI.Canvas.GH_CanvasChannel.Wires) {
            var comp = Owner as KT_HeatmapComponent;
            if (comp == null)
                return;

            List<HeatMap> maps = comp.CachedHeatmaps;
            if (maps == null)
                return;

            if (maps.Count == 0)
                return;

            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width / 2);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Bounds.Bottom + 10);

            for (int i = 0; i < maps.Count; i++) {
                Bitmap image = maps[i].Image;
                if (image == null)
                    continue;

                Rectangle mapBounds = new Rectangle(x, y, maps[i].Width, maps[i].Height);
                mapBounds.X -= mapBounds.Width / 2;

                Rectangle edgeBounds = mapBounds;
                edgeBounds.Inflate(4, 4);

                GH_Capsule capsule = GH_Capsule.CreateCapsule(edgeBounds, GH_Palette.Normal);
                capsule.Render(graphics, Selected, false, false);
                capsule.Dispose();

                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;
                graphics.DrawImage(image, mapBounds);
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Default;
                graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, mapBounds);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Regular Text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new Point(10, 10), SystemColors.ControlText);

                y = edgeBounds.Bottom - (mapBounds.Height) - 4;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code snippet above renders a heatmap onto a Grasshopper canvas, like so:

[image]

However, I am interested in adding title and x/y-axis text onto it.

Comment: Well where do you *expect* `e` to come from? We have no context here - is this in an event handler? Something else?

Comment: Probably the snippet was from a paint handler and was passed an event object named `e`.

Comment: I just learned this is an event handler arg. No, this is not an event handler, so I may be using the wrong method to draw text onto my bitmap. I will be a bit more specific in my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have posted looks like it's designed to be within a `Paint` event handler (since `e` is the idiomatic variable name for the appropriately-typed `EventArgs` for an event handler, and `Graphics` is a property of `PaintEventArgs`).

Since you're being passed a `Graphics` object already, you should just be able to substitute `e.Graphics` in your code snippet with the `graphics` parameter being passed into your `Render` function. You can add this line to that function:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, "Regular Text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new Point(10, 10), SystemColors.ControlText);
```

Comment: `graphics` is already getting passed in as a parameter.  No need to use `CreateGraphics()`

Comment: If I have already declared `graphics` above, what should I do?

Comment: @LarsTech: This was before the question edit which added the function body. All that was originally posted was the single `TextRenderer` line.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not seem to work: http://puu.sh/6dQl0/b35ab90cd3.png I have also tried other gradient schemes, like so: http://puu.sh/6dQm0/9bf93f9bda.png, so the color of the text shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: Try adding it to the end of the function to ensure that nothing is painted over the text.

Comment: That.. Just worked. Interestingly, though, the text is rendered way outside the heatmap image. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: But thanks! You helped solve my issue. I will work out the kinks.